# Añadir variables a una lista mediante ciclo for

Tags: python, pandas, variables, dataframe

estoy creando un conjunto de datos que contiene índices (en el sentido literal) de fascículos de una revista. La forma en que lo estoy haciendo es primero generar todos los índices a mano que serán diccionarios, todos con mismas claves por supuesto y un dataframe vacío cuyas columnas son las claves de los diccionarios. 
Una vez creadas, hago un ciclo con los diccionarios:

```
diccionarios = [dicc_indice1, dicc_indice2, dicc_indice3,\
                dicc_indice4, dicc_indice5, dicc_indice6]
df_total = pd.DataFrame(columns = ('Año','Mes','Número','Título','Autores',\
                                    'Página','Área'))
for dicc in diccionarios:
  df_dicc = pd.DataFrame(dicc)
  df_total = df_total.append(df_dicc, ignore_index = True)
  df_total.to_csv('IyC_índice.csv')
```

dicc_indice1, ... dicc_indice6 son los índices de cada fascículo que los añado en la lista diccionarios para así queden en el dataframe y poder consultar.
El problema es que no son solamente 6 fascículos sino que más de 200, que necesariamente hay que escribirlos. 
Lo que quisiera saber es si en la lista puedo poner directamente las variables, que si bien es lo que hice, quiero hacerlo con un ciclo que sólo dependa del número de diccionarios (todos se llaman igual excepto por el número final), es decir probé con este código pero solamente me genera una lista con cadenas de caracteres y no los diccionarios:

```
diccionarios = []
for elemento in range(1, 3):
 `diccionarios.append('dicc_indice' + str(elemento))`
```

pero claramente me devuelve la lista:

```
diccionarios = ['dicc_indice1', 'dicc_indice2']
```

¿hay alguna forma de añadir mediante un ciclo, variables a una lista? Quizás con expresiones regulares pero creo que sería lo mismo que con caracteres.

Saludos y gracias!
Darío

Comment: Hola Darío, es posible, pero ¿por qué generas los diccionarios manualmente? ¿No es posible hacerlo en un for en vez de manualmente hacer  dicc_indice1 = {...}, dicc_indice1 = {..}?

Comment: Hola, los diccionarios los genero manualmente porque todos los fascículos son distintos, por cada uno hay ocho temas diferentes, áreas y autorías diferentes. No me queda otra que escribirlos, bien podría escribir todo en uno sólo, pero en caso de error de tipeo sería difícil de rastrear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partiendo de la base de que generalmente este tipo de cosas no son la mejor práctica, si no hay más remedio puedes hacerlo de varias formas:

- Usar `getattr`, nos permite obtener cualquier atributo de un objeto dado y dado que en Python todo son objetos, los módulos también:

  ```
  import sys

  dicc_indice1 = {"a": 1}
  dicc_indice2 = {"b": 2}
  dicc_indice3 = {"c": 3}

  diccionarios  = []
  for i in range(1, 4):
      diccionario = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], f"dicc_indice{i}")
      if diccionario is not None:
          diccionarios.append(diccionario)
  ```
- Usar directamente el diccionario `globals` (o `locals` si no son variables globales):

  ```
  dicc_indice1 = {"a": 1}
  dicc_indice2 = {"b": 2}
  dicc_indice3 = {"c": 3}

  diccionarios  = []
  for i in range(1, 4):
      diccionario = globals().get(f"dicc_indice{i}")
      if diccionario is not None:
          diccionarios.append(diccionario)
  ```
- Usar `eval`:

  ```
  dicc_indice1 = {"a": 1}
  dicc_indice2 = {"b": 2}
  dicc_indice3 = {"c": 3}

  diccionarios  = []
  for i in range(1, 4):
      try:
          diccionario = eval(f"dicc_indice{i}")
      except NameError:
          pass
      else:
          diccionarios.append(diccionario)
  ```